# Windows 10 - Headset and speakers show as one sound device (have to unplug headset)?

Tags: usb, audio, speakers, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

Just finished installing Windows 10, and the only issue that I'm encountering pertains to my audio. I have a USB headset and also have USB speakers.

Before, I could leave both of them plugged in and just change the devices in the "Playback" tab from the sound window. However, this "Playback" tab only shows one device right now -- Speakers. So now, I can only hear through my USB speakers if my headset is unplugged, and vice versa. I also have "Show disabled devices" and "Show disconnected devices" enabled.

Any idea how to fix this and put this back on track?

Comment: No Idea but it would be interesting to see what the "Hardware ID" of the 2 devices are in the details of the device manager.  Also if you happen to have a usb3 port capability, and routed a usb2 through that by seeing how it would "connect"  in "view by connection".  What about specific win10 driver items for either of the devices, vrses some genric, or windows update one?

Comment: Nothing changes in device manager when I unplug/plug the headset into the computer, so I can't really find where I'd get the hardware ID for the headset at, although I have it for the USB speakers.

Comment: Nothing from windows updates, and I haven't tried downloading specific drivers for the devices yet. Going to seek that now.

Comment: Still haven't come up with a solution. Think I'm just going to stick with this.

Answer (score 7):

It's the Realtek HD Audio Manager.

In the Control Panel, open the Realtek HD Audio Manager then click "Device advanced settings" in the top right. You want to check 'Make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously' and 'Separate all input jacks as independent input devices'.

[image: Device advanced settings]

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: If you use SupremeFX (Republic of Gamers/ASUS motherboard chipset software), you can find this here via the obscure, top-right settings cog: https://i.imgur.com/LPHnM7h.png

Comment: If you have an HP device with B&O Play audio, then you need to enable the "Multistreaming" option in the B&O settings: https://imgur.com/a/JXx9SUP